# Does Mayavi "Font Size" text property work?

Tags: python, text, fonts, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

Is there a bug in the Mayavi font rendering that prevents changing the font size? I am using the Mayavi2 GUI to change the font size of the axis labels on a volumetric plot.

To get there I go to: Scene -> Scalar Field -> Colors and Legends -> Axes -> Label Text (tab) -> Font Size

Changing this number does not affect the size of the fonts in the image. Is this a known bug? I have seen no reference to it on Google. How do you change the text size on your mayavi figures?

Comment: I have the same issue. Not working in command line either.
I'm using the latest Enthought on Windows 7.

Comment: A workaround for this issue was posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825520/enthought-canopy-mayavi-font-size-bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just downloaded, and installed it, and I seem to be having the same problem. On Windows 8 right now. This is probably a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the independent check. What a shame! It's a beautiful package for making 3D figures...